# Unreal engine reinstancing non-actor handled ensure

Tags: components, unreal-engine4, hot-reload

I've been receiving a strange error after hot-reloading my code:

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsl4V.png) (I'll provide them in text form if needed)

The error references a Notice Range Sphere component. It's just a UDetectionSphere, a simple wrapper for USphereComponent. It used to work correctly, I think the problems begun when I re-parented BaseEnemy from ACharacter to ABaseEntity (see [class graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08udW.png)). The game seems to work fine, but the fact that there is an error can't be a good thing. I also can't [edit component's properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/346uH.png) in editor (both for notice and forget range spheres and for some reason arrow component inherited from ACharacter). Again, it used to work correctly and I was able to edit it. Here's how those components are declared (BaseEnemy.h):

```
public:

UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Setup")
    UDetectionSphere * NoticeRangeSphere;


UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Setup")
    UDetectionSphere * ForgetRangeSphere;
```

I'm pretty sure the error in logs is a simple fix, but I don't even know where to start looking. I can't find this error in google, so it's probably something trivial I'm overlooking. How do I go about fixing this?